# jq string manipulation on domain names and dns records

Tags: json, parsing, jq, reverse

I am attempting to learn some jq but am running into trouble.

I am working with a dataset of dns records like `{"timestamp":"1592145252","name":"0.127.9.109.rev.sfr.net","type":"a","value":"109.9.127.0"}`

I cannot figure out how to

1. strip the subdomain details out of the name field. in this example i just want `sfr.net`
2. print the name backwards, eg: `0.127.9.109.rev.sfr.net` would become `ten.rfs.ver.901.9.721.0`

my end goal is to print lines like this:

`0.127.9.109.rev.sfr.net,ten.rfs.ver.901.9.721.0,a,sfr.net`

Thanks SO!

Comment: As you can see from the answers, it would be helpful if you could specify the requirements more precisely.

Comment: You are right @peak - i could have def done a better job explaining this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the "domain" part, you could use simple string manipulation methods to select it. Assuming anything after the `.rev.` part is the domain, you could do this:

```
split(".rev.")[1]
```

To reverse a string, jq doesn't have the operations to do it directly for strings. However it does have a function to reverse arrays. So you could convert to an array, reverse, then convert back.

```
split("") | reverse | join("")
```

To put it all together for your input:

```
.name | [
    .,
    (split("") | reverse | join("")),
    (split(".rev.")[1])
] | join(",")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! This dataset I am working with has many millions of lines of json, all with different domain names. splitting on the specific domain name will not work for the entire dataset.

Comment: It shouldn't matter so much how many lines of json you have, though it's unclear to me what you consider the "domain" here. The point is, you should be able to get that part either by using basic string manipulations or something a bit more advanced (such as regex).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using `reverse` and `capture`:

```
jq -r '
   .type as $type
   | .name
   | "\(.),\(explode|reverse|implode),\($type)," 
     + capture("(?<subdomain>[^.]+[.][^.]+)$").subdomain'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
$ jq -r '.name' file.json | grep -oE '\w+\.\w+$'
sfr.net
```

```
$ jq -r '.name' file.json | rev
ten.rfs.ver.901.9.721.0
```

Comment: you are technically correct, which is the best kind of correct. I need to edit my question for a proper answer. 1000 apologies. I did upvote your answer though.